# Is considered bad practice to copy a const char ptr without reallocating memory if I'm sure it is in a read-only memory area?

Tags: c++, c

i.e. I initialize a pointer like the following:

```
const char * ptr1 = "Hello";
```

Then I assign the content of the 1st pointer to another pointer, without reallocating/copy the memory and use the latter maybe in another function:

```
const char * ptr2 = ptr1;
```

The first can't be deallocated while I'm use the second, right? 
It can't be modified either.

The only caveat is that I can't check if the memory is read only or not.

But if I'm sure, that the memory is read-only, what can go wrong?

Comment: Nothing can go wrong, because a string literal cannot be deallocated.

Comment: you cannot de-allocate literals.

Comment: Alternatively, if it makes sense, you can assign both pointers to point at `"Hello"`, in which case an optimizing compiler will actually just allocate one single string literal and set both pointers to point at the same memory location. There is usually an optimization feature called "string pooling" which prevents such allocation of duplicate string literals.

Answer (score 2):

> But if I'm sure, that the memory is read-only, what can go wrong?

Nothing, since a string literal is a literal stored within the executable file and cannot be deallocated, ever.

> The first can't be deallocated while I'm use the second, right? It
>   can't be modified either.

Thats correct.

For further explaination, if you do this

```
const char * ptr1 = "Hello";
```

The content of the string is stored *inside your compiled file*, that means you can't deallocate it and neither can any optimization/program.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using **`const`** `char*` it essentially doesn't matter for your question whether the pointer points to a string-literal or some other buffer managed elsewhere.

The `const`here indicates that you can only *read* through this pointer and you can neither `delete` nor `free()` a `const` pointer without a cast.

For the case of string-literals, your `const char * ptr2 = ptr1;` is "safe" , however in general it can be problematic because of:

```
std::string strval1("Foo Bar");
...
const char* ptr1 = strval1.c_str();
...
const char* ptr2 = ptr1;
...
strval1[0] = 'B';
// Both ptr1 and ptr2 point to the original string buffer, thus both now pointing to the modified "Boo Bar" string
```

<sub>Do also note that I intentionally only modified the string in-place above, because that is [guaranteed to preserve the buffer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) (-> *... invalidated by: ...  Calling non-const member functions ..., **excluding** `operator[]`, `at()`, ...*). Had I appended to the string, the pointer obtained through `.c_str()`above would have been invalidated.</sub>